# Why are insertions into ListMap O(n)?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

According to scala documentation, [insertions into the ListMap are O(n)](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.html)

> Other operations, such as inserting or removing entries, are also O(n), which makes this collection suitable only for a small number of elements.

Shouldn't inserting into the head of a linked list be O(1)? Why is insertion O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an element to a non-empty `ListMap`, the `updated` method of `ListMap.Node` is called. In a worst-case scenario, it scans the whole collection to check if the key already exists (as you suggested in your comment):
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a2cf63ee5bad8c8c054f76464de0e10226516a0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/ListMap.scala#L173